# Can't read url params in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problems on deploying a site in laravel to a server.

When working on localhost I can read params from URL like

```
.../v1/test?a=hi&b=bye
```

I use `Input::all()` to see every param available. I also check it with `$_GET`and both display the params I pass.

Once I deploy it to the server I can't seem to read any param from the URL with `Input::all()` nor `$_GET`. What I get is

```
Array
(
    [/v1/test] => 
)
```

I've checked the server config with a simple PHP and I can read it so I guess it's some kind of trickery.

I'm using PHP 5.4.24 on server and 5.4.7 on localhost

Comment: What web server? Are you sending normal GET requests or some JSON stuff?

Comment: You'll have a much easier life if you run the same version live as you do local. Although I understand this isn't always possible, in cases such as shared hosting for example.

Comment: I'm trying it with normal GET as I don't get JSON stuff to work, so I'm testing

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was with .htaccess

The rewrite mode changed the URL and made it impossible to see the vars

I've gone back to the default htaccess (which I don't recall changing)

You can find it here:
[laravel's htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)