# Cannot read url params in laravel5.2 in remote server

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

My issue is, the value passed is received alright in blade in my local server. But in my remote server, blade file cannot access the value set in controller. Why that might be?Can somebody help please?

In HomeController

```
 public function getDetails(Request $request) {
    echo $url = $request->input('url');
    return view('home.details')->with('url', $url);
}
```

Here, no value is echoed.
Looks Like the real problem is, in remote server I am not being able to read url params for some reason.

Any sugestion please?

Comment: Is the value set, that is, does the `$url` var got any value when passed (or does `$request->input('url');` return null? If you set the variable to something else before passing it to view, will it show then?

Comment: It's null!! I found it yesterday after I posted my question.. The line $request->input('name') it doesn't work in my remote server! Though it does in my local.. what is the problem. Can you guess please? @Jite

Comment: When it comes to why it works on one but not another computer, I would say that it could be due to many different reasons. The most likely reason would be that there are different versions on the apache (if that is what you use?) server software.

Answer (score 1):

[Can't read url params in php laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132398/cant-read-url-params-in-php-laravel#new-answer)

This url has my answer! The problem seems with the .htaccess file. The confusion is, why it works in my local server then?

I used the .htaccess described in following link

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Just I added

> RewriteRule ^(.*)(images|css|js|fonts|upload|plugins|img|ckeditor)(.+)$ public/$2$3 [L]

the line above because of my apps folder arrangements. So far it's working fine now.

> **Though the question is answered, I will appreciate if somebody could explain why the same .htaccess that works in my local doesn't in my remote?**